# Using a list as key-value pair to be inserted

Tags: python, dictionary, split

Hello I have a list that I wish to insert into a dictionary - however not each element a new element in the dictionary - the list itself is 2 items long and should be used as "key-value" pair.

Or (as knowing python there are dozens of ways to do something so maybe this isn't even necessary). The base problem is that I wish to split a string into 2 parts around a delimiter and use the left as "key" and the right as "value":

```
for line in file:
    if "=" in line:
        tpair = line.split("=",1)
        constantsMap.update(tpair)
```

Of course I could do a manual split like:

```
for line in file:
    if "=" in line:
        p = line.find("=")
        constantsMap[line[:p]] = line[p+1:]
```

But that doesn't seem to be idiomaticcally "python", so I was wondering if there's a more clean way?

Comment: ps: already answered (waiting for time) - but care to explain the downvote?

Comment: If the answer is simple, some people downvote with the attitude of "why couldn't you think of that?"  They forget though that in Python, everything is simple. :)

Comment: "everything is simple"  and in the process python became terribly complex to me.  8086 Assembly is simple - there's only so many opcodes to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) here:

```
key,val = line.split("=", 1)
constantsMap[key] = val
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> line = "a=1"
>>> constantsMap = {}
>>> key,val = line.split("=", 1)
>>> constantsMap[key] = val
>>> constantsMap
{'a': '1'}
>>>
```